# WCF unsuported media type

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

I have a WCF webservice to receive files but when i make a post call always return me Unsuported media type multipart-form-data when i try to send a file, if i dont send file and set contentype to xml, service get me an OK and create the file pruebffa.jpg fine
this is my web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="streamBinding" transferMode="Streamed" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxReceivedMessageSize="615424521" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"/>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
        <service name="WcfService3.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WcfService3.Service1Behavior">
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="streamBinding" contract="WcfService3.IService1">
                <identity>
                    <dns value="localhost"/>
                </identity>
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WcfService3.Service1Behavior">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true. Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate="")] 
    void UploadImage(Stream image);
}

public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public void UploadImage(Stream image)
    {
        var buf = new byte[1024];
        var path = Path.Combine(@"C:\", "pruebffa.jpg");
        int len = 0;
        using (var fs = File.Create(path))
        {
            while ((len = image.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length)) > 0)
            {
                fs.Write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i enabled to accept multipart/form-data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's a POST operation you should use `WebInvoke` instead of `WebGet`.

```
[OperationContract]     
[WebInvoke(..)]      
void UploadImage(Stream image);
```